# Reverse button colors when pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to go for a button with this style:

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

[image: otherbuttons]

However, I'm unsure of how to get the right colors for the button when it's being pressed like the middle button in the example. I've managed to get the color of the image to turn white by using:

```
button.setImage(UIImage("Image_White_Version"), for: .highlighted)
```

But I don't know how to fill the rest of the button with color. Can anybody please help me out?

Comment: Well, you also have to change the `backgroundImage` for `highlighted` state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the background image of a UIButton for a specific state like this:

```
let image = UIImage.imageWithColor(someColor, size: CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0))
btn.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .highlighted)
```

Here is a function for creating an image from a color (put inside an extension on UIImage):

```
extension UIImage {
    class func imageWithColor(_ color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context!.fill(rect)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `UIControl` instead of `UIButton` and just change the `tint` for the image and `backgroundColor` when highlighted.

Comment: `Type 'UIImage' has no member 'imageWithColor'`

Comment: No, you have to add the extension i posted in my answer.

Comment: Do you set the clipsToBounds property on your button to true?

Comment: Thanks @bughana, that fixed it. But do you know why the image is showing up as so faint? I'm using                                               `button.setImage(UIImage(named: "Food")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .highlighted)
                                                                    button.tintColor = UIColor.white`

Comment: Hm... is there a reason why you draw the image with a rendering mode, specifically the "alwaysTemplate"? Apple's documentation states this: "Always draw the image as a template image, ignoring its color information.", so i would try removing that code and just use the plain image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use next approach:

*It's the fast way how to achive this. Main idea use button background color and image tint color. But better way prepare new custom control on base UIControl. If it would be not enpught I will prepare it for you.*

```
    var BgColorNormalIdentifier = "BackgroundColorNormal"
    var BgColorHighlightedIdentifier = "BackgroundColorHighlighted"
    var ImgColorNormalIdentifier = "ImageColorNormal"
    var ImgColorHighlightedIdentifier = "ImageColorHighlighted"

    public extension UIButton
    {
        public func backgroundColorForStates(normal: UIColor, highlighted: UIColor)
        {
            backgroundColor = normal

            addTarget(self, action:#selector(UIButton.buttonTouchUpInside(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)
            addTarget(self, action:#selector(UIButton.buttonTouchUpOutside(_:)), for:.touchUpOutside)
            addTarget(self, action:#selector(UIButton.buttonTouchDown(_:)), for:.touchDown)
            addTarget(self, action:#selector(UIButton.buttonTouchCancel(_:)), for:.touchCancel)

            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &BgColorNormalIdentifier, normal, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &BgColorHighlightedIdentifier, highlighted, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &ImgColorNormalIdentifier, highlighted, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &ImgColorHighlightedIdentifier, normal, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }

        public func imageForState (image: UIImage?, for state: UIControlState) {
            self.setImage(image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: state)
        }

        public func normalBackgroundColor() -> UIColor?
        {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &BgColorNormalIdentifier) as? UIColor
        }

        public func highlightedBackgroundColor() -> UIColor?
        {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &BgColorHighlightedIdentifier) as? UIColor
        }

        public func normalImageColor() -> UIColor?
        {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &ImgColorNormalIdentifier) as? UIColor
        }

        public func highlightedImageColor() -> UIColor?
        {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &ImgColorHighlightedIdentifier) as? UIColor
        }

        func buttonTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton)
        {
            sender.backgroundColor = normalBackgroundColor()
            sender.tintColor = normalImageColor()
        }

        func buttonTouchUpOutside(_ sender: UIButton)
        {
            sender.backgroundColor = normalBackgroundColor()
            sender.tintColor = normalImageColor()
        }

        func buttonTouchDown(_ sender: UIButton)
        {
            sender.backgroundColor = highlightedBackgroundColor()
            sender.tintColor = highlightedBackgroundColor()
        }

        func buttonTouchCancel(_ sender: UIButton)
        {
            sender.backgroundColor = normalBackgroundColor()
            sender.tintColor = normalImageColor()
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is some code in your post which is not in the code format block